# Scrolling to a row

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I need to be able to scroll to the last row at the bottom in reactjs ag-grid, on click of button.

I tried below but its scrolling to the first row  instead on the top of the grid.

```
gridApi.ensureIndexVisible(gridApi.getDisplayedRowCount(), "bottom");
```

Am I missing something here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake you're making is scrolling to `gridApi.getDisplayedRowCount()`, you need to scroll to `gridApi.getDisplayedRowCount() - 1`, because the row count will always be more than the 0 based index. I.e. if you have 41 rows, the index of the bottom row will be 40, not 41.

Change your code to:

```
gridApi.ensureIndexVisible(gridApi.getDisplayedRowCount() - 1, "bottom");
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-react-hello-world-etcrn9?file=index.js)

Comment: Thanks @ViqMontana. Yes, I had tried gridApi.getDisplayedRowCount() - 1 earlier,  but no luck. It did not do anything wrt scrolling.